# Instagram API not returning followers

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm authenticated with Instagram, and I got an access token with scope `follower_list`. Then I tried to get my followers list:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by?access_token=123.456`

and all I got was an empty array, like following

```
{
    "pagination": {},
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "data": []
}
```

I don't really know if this is a problem from Instagram side or this is an expected behavior since I'm on Sandbox mode (although the documentation says I can expect to get real data even on Sandbox mode)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

In sandbox mode you will only get data from you and your sandbox users.

Add one of your followers to your sandbox, then only that user will be in API response. Once you go live, all users will be in API response.

Comment: I am trying to get a list of my own followers, I am the only user in the sandbox, and I am still having the same issue as OP. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @VladHQ if you are the only one in sandbox, then u will get empty data, add one user that u follows you to sandbox, then only that user will show up in api response, once u go live and have public_content approved, you willl see all users in api response

Comment: @krisrak Is the invited sandbox user supposed to be registered as a developer on instagram?